# BigQuery load job response: inputFileBytes versus outputBytes - what does each describe

Tags: google-bigquery

As far as I can tell, BigQuery's documentation is vague about this, so asking here:

After a load job is complete, BigQuery returns statistics about the completed job (example below). The values for inputFileBytes and outputBytes often differ, but it's not documented as to why. My two questions:

a. Does "inputFileBytes" describe the size of the staged file(s) stored in GCS? (If this is a compressed file, this should report the size of that file, not the size uncompressed, correct?)

b. Does "outputBytes" describe the resulting amount of
   bytes stored in BigQuery (i.e. the amount that the user will be
   charged for?)

```
 "statistics": {
  "creationTime": "1455758097056",
  "startTime": "1455758114405",
  "endTime": "1455758123900",
  "load": {
   "inputFiles": "1",
   "inputFileBytes": "2648200",
   "outputRows": "23210",
   "outputBytes": "8075071"
  }
```

Comment: That's how I always thought of these attributes. But I suspect (because you ask) you see something that doesn't fit to this. Do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `inputFileBytes` should describe the byte size of the files as BigQuery sees them. If you are loading a `.gz` file, it will be the size of the file, and not the size of the uncompressed data.

The field `outputBytes` describes the byte size of the just loaded data. Yes, this corresponds to the user billable byte size.